QGIS 3.34 automated field value update for complete column
I am using QGIS 3.34.5.
I have a polygon with three features.
In the attribute form I included the following formular for automatically updating the feature area: "area ($geometry)". The respective attribute field is "feature_area"
Thus, every time a feature is changed, the respective field value will be automatically updated.
I created another column with the name "area_sum" that represents the total area of all (three) features. In the attribute form I included the formula: "sum ("feature_area")".
Thus, QGIS is calculating the total area of all features and filling all rows with the same value as intended.
Unfortunately, if I change a single feature now, only the "area_sum" for the respective feature is updated, but the "area_sum" values for the other two features remain unchanged.
I also tried "sum(area($geometry))" getting the same results.

You could use a virtual field to hold the total area.  Here is an example:


This is the way, use default expression if you only want to update the active feature, and use virtual field if you want to update all features.

Unfortunately, a virtual field did not achieve the correct result. If I now change the vertices of a single feature, the "total_area" field is not updated automatically but remains the same value. Thus, I have to update the virtual field manually again.
Additionally in your example the "total_area" does not have the same value for all rows as intended.

If you re-open the table you should see the virtual field is updated.  Alternatively, you could use the formula sum($area) in the virtual field.

My mistake was expecting the change in the field values for the total_area "on the fly". After closing and reopening the attribute table, all feature values of the total_area are correctly updated.
